# Send periodically mouse event and key events. (Pretend as working) using C#

Tags: c#

I want to make window active. 
Scroll it, click on it. Just to show someone is working on it.

These methods are not working for this task.

```
Mouse.MouseDownEvent;
Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
```

Comment: Would this "someone" be you? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this function (C++) so you will have to pinvoke it. You can get the current windows (C# Form) handle easily.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit: it seems someone did the hard work to pinvoke this method before check this out:

http://boycook.wordpress.com/2008/07/29/c-win32-messaging-with-sendmessage-and-wm_copydata/